# loading different text in same view controller

Tags: objective-c, text, uiviewcontroller

Hi I have a quiz app that I am working on, and on my RootViewController I have two buttons with action methods, now when I press on one of the buttons I get my questionViewController and text is loaded into specific fields, I do this by using the viewDidLoad method. When I go back to the RootViewController and click on a different button I want to show the same questionViewController but with different text, how can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I just finished a project with similar requirement.  One way to do this is to use static variable and class method in your questionViewController class.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement `viewDidAppear:` on your questionViewController, and set the text there instead of `viewDidLoad`.

You could also implement a method on questionViewController, that updated the text fields, and call this method from the RootViewController.